# Atalasoft Wingscan ImportDocument Not Being Called When Importing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, scanning

I am trying to scan through a browser using Atalasoft's Wingscan product.
I have the scan working correctly, however the upload to the appropriate server directory is not working.  I am using the
 
button as described in the Wingscan sample documentation.  The expected behavior would be to access the overriden ImportDocument function and perform the required business logic.

```
Protected Overrides Function ImportDocument(context As HttpContext, filename As String, contentType As String, contentTypeDocumentClass As String, contentTypeDescription As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

When debugging the function is never accessed.
Any ideas or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any and all assistance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing the following code

```
 Atalasoft.Controls.Capture.CaptureService.initialize({
                handlerUrl: 'ScanningHandler.ashx'
            });
```